# MySQL - How to delete rows where column does not contain certain values?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete all rows where a specific column does not contain certain strings. 
Like this:

```
DELETE * FROM table
WHERE Disease NOT LIKE (Malaria, HIV, E. coli O157);
```

I get this error:
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; near '* FROM table WHERE Disease NOT LIKE (Malaria' at line 1**

Comment: Remove the "*", change "LIKE" to "IN", and put single quotes around your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Disease not in ('Malaria', 'HIV', 'E. coli 0157');
```

put your actual name of the table in place of TABLE_NAME in the above statement.

Answer (score 5):

If the description given is the exact description of the disease, just use `NOT IN` (with proper quotes):

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE Disease NOT IN ('Malaria', 'HIV', 'E. coli O157');
```

but if it is a substring, you have to use multiple `LIKE`:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE
  NOT (Disease LIKE '%Malaria%'
       or Disease LIKE '%HIV%'
       or Disease LIKE '%E. coli O157%');
```